# How to detect head motion with android gyroscope?

Tags: android, accelerometer, gyroscope

I am trying to create an android app where a user attaches the phone to the head in the portrait position and does simple and slow exercises and my app gives them audio commands based on the position of the body. I am using accelerometer reading and tracking gravity for all movements that are not along the y axis. I have one simple exercise motion in which the user moves his head 45 degrees to left or right while sitting upright. I cannot track this motion as the movement does not change the gravity on the phone too much. I tried using the gyroscope but it gives unpredictable readings. Can someone suggest me ways of tracking this movement? Please ask me if I was not clear in explaining the movement.